# Konva Objects are there in memory even after destroying the component in angular 5

Tags: angular, performance, html5-canvas, konvajs

I have an angular component in which we are using konva. Due to some action by the end user we will hide and show the component by means of css. Our angular ngOnDestroy function is getting called, but in memory profiling of browser there are many konva related objects are there.

Comment: Can you make a demo?